# Tilt compensation for stationary 3-axis accelerometer

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, accelerometer, sensors, rotational-matrices

I'm working on a sensor that uses a three axis mems accelerometer. The sensor will be stationary and measure vibrations. However, I would like to compensate for a sensor that is not perfectly mounted by using a rotational matrix and calculating the x,y,z values as if it was mounted perfectly in plane. I hope I made myself understood. Any tips or reading would be appreciated. I know I found a paper on this once but after googling for three days, I have not been able to find it again.

Does anyone know how to achieve such a rotational matrix?

Take care friends!

Comment: You forgot to _ask a question_, this is just a problem statement. Where are you stuck? If it's with the actual maths required, this might be better suited to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com), otherwise you should [edit] your question to include a [mcve]; we don't need to care about where your data comes from other than for context, but show an example measurement, the desired output, and where you're stuck in achieving that.

Comment: edited with a question

Comment: That wasn't really the point of my comment, I wasn't just pointing out the semantics of whether you had a questioning sentence, but rather I tried to highlight how you'd generally improve the question with details about your specific issue, hopefully including an example. Please read [ask].

Comment: @nwretborn Some additional details that would help: What is the plane in question? A local level plane with gravity (actually reaction force) perpendicular to the plane? Which axis is up/down? Can you give an example of a vector output, and what that output would look like if it were mounted perfectly? Do you have sample outputs where there isn't any vibration going on? Etc.